# Assimp 5.0.0 crash on export

Tags: assimp, exporter

I'm trying to export my aiScene (which worked correctly with assimp 4.1.0), and I get a crash every time that the procedure ends and the export function it's called.
I subclassed aiScene and the constructor looks like this:

```
customAiScene::customAiScene()
{
    mFlags = 0;
    mRootNode = NULL;
    mNumMeshes = 0;
    mMeshes = NULL;
    mNumMaterials = 0;
    mMaterials = NULL;
    mNumAnimations = 0;
    mAnimations = NULL;
    mNumTextures = 0;
    mTextures = NULL;
    mNumLights = 0;
    mLights = NULL;
    mNumCameras = 0;
    mCameras = NULL;
    mPrivate = NULL;
    exporter = new Assimp::Exporter();
    int n = exporter->GetExportFormatCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        const aiExportFormatDesc* formatDescription = exporter->GetExportFormatDescription(i);
        wxString sDesc = wxString::FromUTF8(formatDescription->description);
        wxString sExt = wxString::FromUTF8(formatDescription->fileExtension);
        wxString sID = wxString::FromUTF8(formatDescription->id);
        MyApp::showMessage(wxString::Format(wxT("export format: %s,%s,%s"), sDesc, sExt, sID), "l");
    }
}
```

Later on, after setting the data, I export the scene:

```
exporter->Export(this, exportFormatDesc, filePath);
```

As I said, with assimp 4.1.0 it is working correctly (but I need FBX export hence the reason for the new version).
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I will check your code with our current master. This seems to be a bug.

I opened the issue-report https://github.com/assimp/assimp/issues/2846 to track your issue.